# How to load proper value in Autocomplete MUI from DB

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new in MUI and try to replace my Select combo with Autocomplete. For now i maked to load proper value and save it in SQL Server DB but i don't know what and how to put in value property to visualize of component to load and select proper value. Data From this combo will save in **insurance.autoUserId**

```
interface IState {
    insurance: InsuranceModel;
    autoUsers: Array<AutoUserModel>;
    autoUserDropdown: Array<DropdownModelCombo>;
    autoUserSelectedValue:Array<DropdownModelCombo>;
}
constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            insurance: props.currentInsurance,
            autoUsers: new Array<AutoUserModel>(),
            autoUserDropdown: new Array<DropdownModelCombo>(),
            autoUserSelectedValue: new Array<DropdownModelCombo>(),
        };
    }
```

ComponentDidMount

```
 this.autoUserService.getAllActiveAutoUsers().then(
                (data: any) => {
                    const autoUserDropdown1 : Array<DropdownModelCombo> = [];
                    data.map(autoUser => {
        
                        autoUserDropdown1.push({
                                value:autoUser.autoUserId,
                                label:autoUser.autoUserName
            
                            }
                        )
                   });
                   this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        autoUsers: data,
                        autoUserDropdown: autoUserDropdown1,
                    });

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.snackbar.show({ severity: 'error', summary: error.message });
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                });
```

Autocomplete Compopent

```
 <Autocomplete
disablePortal
id="combo-box-demo"
value={?????}
options={autoUserDropdown}
sx={{ width: 300 }}
onChange={(e, value) => this.handleChangeSelectAutoComplete( e, value, 'autoUserId')}
renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="AutoUser" />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I must to return DropdownModelCombo object with proper data that i get from autoUsers where **autoUserId** is equal to **this.state.insurance.autoUserId**

```
const autoUserval: DropdownModelCombo ={value: 0, label: ""};
const id = this.state.insurance.autoUserId;
                    data.map(autoUser => {

                        if(autoUser.autoUserId===id)
                        {
                            autoUserval.value = autoUser.autoUserId;
                            autoUserval.label = autoUser.autoUserName;

                        }

                    });
 this.setState({autoUserValue: autoUserval});
```